# log4net coloredConsoleAppender not showing any color

Tags: visual-studio-2012, log4net

I am trying to configure log4net to log coloured text to the console with the following settings.

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
    <mapping>
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <foreColor value="Red" />
      <backColor value="Green" />
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <foreColor value="White" />
      <backColor value="Green" />
    </mapping>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%thread]  %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <!-- Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to ColoredConsoleAppender -->
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

However, the error logs are not coming out as red color. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add mappings (kind of lame they don't seem to have defaults set).

```
var console = new ColoredConsoleAppender
{
    Layout = patternLayout
};
console.AddMapping(new ColoredConsoleAppender.LevelColors()
{
    BackColor = ColoredConsoleAppender.Colors.Yellow,
    ForeColor = ColoredConsoleAppender.Colors.Red,
    Level = Level.Info
});
console.ActivateOptions();
hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(console);
```

And if you're more of a config/xml kind of guy:

```
<mapping>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <foreColor value="White" />
    <backColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
</mapping>
<mapping>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <backColor value="Green" />
</mapping>
```

[Source](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case, it was a inaccurate config (the mapping element was inside layout element, and it should be just inside appender element). Check your config file.